# Asymptotics of mean exit time $E_x[T_R(x)] \asymp R^a$ equivalent to $E_x[(X_t-x)^2] \asymp t^{2/a}$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Assume $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a real valued strong Markov process starting in $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and define  $T_{R}(x):=\inf(s \geq 0 | X_s \notin (-R+x,R+x) \}$. Is the following statement true?
>
> $ 
> \mathbb{E}_x[T_R(x)]  \asymp R^{\alpha}
> $
>   is equivalent to 
>   $
> \mathbb{E}_x[(X_t-x)^2]  \asymp t^{2/\alpha}
> $
>   for a $\alpha>0$.

Here  $\asymp $ means that here exists $c_1,c_2,t_0>0$ such that
$ c_2 t^{2/\alpha} \leq 
\mathbb{E}_x[(X_t-x)^2] \leq c_1 t^{2/\alpha}.
$
for $t>t_0$.

For example for the Brownian Motion the statement is true for $\alpha=2$ because
$\mathbb E_x[T_{r}(x)]=R^2$ and $\mathbb{E}_x[(B_t-x)^2]=t^{2/2}$.

Maybe this holds true for general stochastic processes?

$\textbf{EDIT}$

Set $R=t^{1/d_W}$ then one obtains
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_x[T_R(x)] \asymp t
\end{align*}
So the expected time leaving the ball $(-t^{1/d_w}+x,-t^{1/d_w}+x)$ is linear in $t$.
So in a heuristic way one would expect:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_x[(X_t-x)^2] \asymp t^{2/d_w}.
\end{align*}

Thanks in advance for any partial answer.